# How to avoid Javascript Garbage Collection when making function returns

Tags: javascript, function, garbage-collection

Am I right in thinking that,

1. With each call, test() exports another new object that must be garbage collected later.

   ```
   var sumValue=test(0,3);

   function test(startingValue,n){
       return({sum:startingValue+n});
   }
   ```
2. This version of test() requires no garbage collection later.

   ```
   var sumValue={sum:0};
   test(sumValue,3);

   function test(output,n){
       output.sum+=n;
   }
   ```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid garbage collection?

Comment: It all depends on whether the purpose is to modify an existing object of to have different objects with different `sum` properties.

Comment: You generally don't have to worry about garbage collection in javascript, there's not much you can do to affect it anyway, except in very special cases. Most of the time you can just assume that Google, Apple etc. have people employed that are smart enough to create efficient automatic garbage collection that just works like it should. On the other hand, any data structure you create will be garbage collected when the engine decides it's no longer useful, so creating many objects would be more expensive than just modifying a single object, but you'll never notice the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, on each call it will create a new object.
2. Yes, since you're just mutating the existing object.

For this specific case, I wouldn't worry about it. It's too small to make an impact (unless this code is being run multiple times for extended periods).